# can you user node server as a potential storage for minimal JSON object?

Tags: node.js

I have an JSON object the has the size of about 350kb a list of items about 1500 item , I don't want to keep it on the front end but yet I don't want to use database either can I store it in node.js and call it from there each time the data are needed ? I have no idea if this can be considered a bad practice what do you think ?

Comment: You can save it to a file.

Comment: you mean like normal file ?

Comment: Yeah, Because NodeJs does not have any persistent storage itself.

Comment: What is max size limit ?

Comment: Yes, 256 Terabyte per file if you are on windows.